# Boost library or equivalent implementation of C++0x atomic for Sutter's lock-free queue?

Tags: c++, concurrency, queue, fifo, lock-free

Herb Sutter's article on lock-free and concurrent queues has been mentioned quite a bit here in SO.  However, I don't have a C++0x compiler...so I'm wondering if anyone has translated his code to use either some boost library or whatever to provide some "atomic" operation.

I wouldn't mind, even, if anyone can provide a mutex/condition_variable example...

Here are the articles I'm referring to...

http://drdobbs.com/cpp/210604448

http://drdobbs.com/cpp/211601363

http://drdobbs.com/high-performance-computing/212201163

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intel's [Thread Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) has an atomic data structure.

The [Boost Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/thread.html) library is also a good place to find various mutexes and condition variables.